# Mailchimp 'Style Declaration Block' not working

Tags: css, email, mailchimp

I have some custom styles in my email that I'd like to make available for use in the WYSIWYG editor. I followed [this guide](https://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/template-language/) but my styles aren't showing up.  What can I do differently?  Also, is there any way to remove unused styles like 
`TOC heading`?

```
  /**
  * @tab Page
  * @tip Set the styling for all first-level headings in your emails.
  * @style heading 1
  */
  h1{
    line-height:1;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#24a9a4;
    font-family:Source Sans Pro,Helvetica,Arial;
    text-shadow:2px 2px 0 #ffde17;
    margin:5px 0;
    font-size:65px;
  }
```

In the email the styling looks fine:

[image]

But in the dropdown menu I can't see any of my styles:

[image]

Comment: Where's your `/*@editable*/` comments on each line?

Comment: The style declaration blocks refer to options in the general design column in MailChimp's campaign editor. MailChimp uses [tag:CKEditor] as it's WYSIWYG editor, a user cannot make changes to the style options in CKEditor itself (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
* @tab Page
* @section Heading 1
* @tip Set the styling for all first-level headings in your emails.
* @style heading 1
*/
h1{
  /*@editable*/ line-height:1;
  /*@editable*/ font-weight:bold;
  /*@editable*/ color:#24a9a4;
  /*@editable*/ font-family:Source Sans Pro,Helvetica,Arial;
  /*@editable*/ text-shadow:2px 2px 0 #ffde17;
  /*@editable*/ margin:5px 0;
  /*@editable*/ font-size:65px;
}
```

Try adding the /*@editable*/ to each line.

Comment: If this worked for you can you click the green and close the question? Thank you and good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately that wasn't the solution, though I tried it: "Style declaration blocks share a basic structure regardless of the element style targeted and the /*@editable*/ declaration repeats for each element you want to be editable within an area."

Comment: You know I have actually never tried this in MC, now I want to - see if I get the same results :D